# Fill in the Dashes : Part 4 of 10 - Subject Who?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

This is part of the [Fill in the Dashes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22Fill%20in%20the%20Dashes%22) series of puzzles.

Example : F_ in the B_ ⇒ Fill in the Blanks

Some of the words will be Juxtaposed as in

e.g. : C_ K_ S_ ⇒ Clark Kent Superman or Superman Clark Kent

---

A I_ M_ S_ T_ 2

C_ I_ T_ 1

D_ S_ S_ T_ 15

F_ L_ N_ 1

E_ P_ 1

D_ M_ T_ Y_ 11

F_ I_ S_ T_ 4

H_ H_ T_ 1

D_ I J_ O_ 4

B_ L_ P_ T_ 8

C_ D_ T_ 4

M_ O_ O_ S_ T_ 4

F_ N_ T_ 4

Who am I?

Hint 1

> Each line identifies a creation of the personality

Hint 2

> The personality fame was for his writing.

Hint 3

> Was popular and connected to Hollywood

Additional Information:

> Any one correct should reveal the rest. I will accept the first correct answer as complete.

Comment: And what about the numbers?  That wasn't in the example, what do they represent?

Comment: @qwertylpc I think it might have to do with the Who am I? question at the end

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to create a tag specifically for one of your questions. We don't get many questions categorized as "personality", for example.

Comment: Also regarding your first clue, shouldn't it be An I____

Comment: @mmking Thank you. I will remove the tag.

Comment: @quertylpc the numbers can be ignored in the first run and later can be used to reveal the answer.

Comment: I think a trivia tag might be relevant.

Comment: @kanchirk Once again, should it be An I____ for the first clue?

Comment: @qwertylpc Sorry. It is only A.

Comment: @qwertylpc OP said that the words might be mixed up.

Comment: Hint please....

Comment: @quertylpc Adding now as requested.

Comment: Can fill some with Isaac Asimov works but too much are missing

Comment: Hm, i wonder about "is famous for..." and "was popular and...".  1st one implies he is still alive, second one that he is dead...

Comment: @kl78 You have a point. Two more hints : He indeed is dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Who Am I?

> American writer, Sidney Sheldon

His works...

A I_ M_ S_ T_ 2

> (**A** **I**n **M**irror **S**tranger **T**he / A Stranger In The Mirror)

C_ I_ T_ 1

> (**C**omes **I**f **T**omorrow / If Tomorrow Comes)

D_ S_ S_ T_ 15

> (**D**own **S**tars **S**hine **T**he / The Stars Shine Down)

F_ L_ N_ 1

> (**F**orever **L**asts **N**othing / Nothing Lasts Forever)

E_ P_ 1

> (**E**aster **P**arade)

D_ M_ T_ Y_ 11

> (**D**reams **M**e **T**ell **Y**our / Tell Me Your Dreams)

F_ I_ S_ T_ 4

> (**F**alling **I**s **S**ky **T**he / The Sky Is Falling)

H_ H_ T_ 1

> (**H**art **H**art **T**o / Hart to Hart)

D_ I J_ O_ 4

> (**D**ream **I** **J**eannie **O**f / I Dream of Jeannie)

B_ L_ P_ T_ 8

> (**B**est **L**aid **P**lans **T**he / The Best Laid Plans)

C_ D_ T_ 4

> (**C**onspiracy **D**oomsday **T**he / The Doomsday Conspiracy)

M_ O_ O_ S_ T_ 4

> (**M**idnight **O**ther **O**f **S**ide **T**he / The Other Side of Midnight)

F_ N_ T_ 4

> (**F**ace **N**aked **T**he / The Naked Face)

But I don't know what the numbers stand for lol

Comment: Congratulations !!! I am accepting your answer since the Numbers extract the letter of each position to spell of Sidney Sheldon.

Comment: Oh wow yeah I was NEVER going to get that. Good job!